# Multiple site not working after move magento from local to server

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, e-commerce

I moved magento  from local to server: everything is working fine but multiple website is not working. When I enter the exact url I don't receive any error. It seems like url opens, but when I click on products category it shows default websites products and price. But on localhost everything is working fine.

I changed .htaccess file with default .htaccess of magento new installation.

I also tried rewritebase but I don't know if I did it correctly or not because I can't find  a good explanation.

> Note:multiple website are on same domain in different directories

Answer (score 0):

Check the all the files and folders' attribute and permission on the web server they have to have file permission of 777 (run chmod 777 on your terminal for the web server).

Comment: Lol you can every folder need 755 and filess need 644 where to you lear this ??????

Answer (score 0):

One option is to check if server has **mod_rewrite** enabled.

Another option is to add code below to index.php and define domain to store

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "abc.com" || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "www.abc.com"){
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = "en";
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_TYPE"] = "store";
}

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "abc.de" || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "www.abc.de"){
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = "de";
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_TYPE"] = "store";
}

/* Store or website code */
```

Comment: multiple website are on same domain in different directories

Comment: So you have one installation? Do you have option "Add Store Code to Urls" enabled?